# python pandas text block to data frame mixed types

Tags: python, pandas, frame, data-conversion

I am a python and pandas newbie. I have a text block that has data arranged in columns. The data in the first six columns are integers and the rest are floating point. I tried to create two DataFrames that I could then concatenate:

```
sect1 = DataFrame(dtype=int)
sect2 = DataFrame(dtype=float)
i = 0
# The first 26 lines are header text
for line in txt[26:]:
    colmns = line.split()
    sect1[i] = colmns[:6]  # Columns with integers
    sect2[i] = colmns[6:]  # Columns with floating point
    i +=
```

This causes an AssertionError: Length of values does not match length of index

Here are two lines of data

```
2013 11 15  0000   56611      0   1.36e+01  3.52e-01  7.89e-02  4.33e-02  3.42e-02  1.76e-02  2.89e+04  5.72e+02 -1.00e+05
2013 11 15  0005   56611    300   1.08e+01  5.50e-01  2.35e-01  4.27e-02  3.35e-02  1.70e-02  3.00e+04  5.50e+02 -1.00e+05
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pandas [csv parser](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas-io-parsers-read-csv) along with [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO). [An example in pandas documentation.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

For you sample that will be:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> data = """2013 11 15  0000   56611      0   1.36e+01  3.52e-01  7.89e-02  4.33e-02  3.42e-02  1.76e-02  2.89e+04  5.72e+02 -1.00e+05
... 2013 11 15  0005   56611    300   1.08e+01  5.50e-01  2.35e-01  4.27e-02  3.35e-02  1.70e-02  3.00e+04  5.50e+02 -1.00e+05"""
```

Load data

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s+', header=None)
```

Convert first three rows to datetime (optional)

```
>>> df[0] = df.iloc[:,:3].apply(lambda x:'{}.{}.{}'.format(*x), axis=1).apply(pd.to_datetime)
>>> del df[1]
>>> del df[2]
>>> df
                   0   3      4    5     6      7       8       9       10  \
0 2013-11-15 00:00:00   0  56611    0  13.6  0.352  0.0789  0.0433  0.0342
1 2013-11-15 00:00:00   5  56611  300  10.8  0.550  0.2350  0.0427  0.0335

       11     12   13      14
0  0.0176  28900  572 -100000
1  0.0170  30000  550 -100000
```

Comment: I edited the question to show two lines of data.

I tried this:
import StringIO
pd.read_table(StringIO(txt[26:]))

but got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @user2825739 read my answer carefully, you should `from StringIO import StringIO` instead `import StringIO`. That's a bit confusing, but StringIO module has StringIO class inside.

Comment: I did that:

from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt[26:]), sep=r'\s+', header=None)

print df



and it gave me this:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0

Columns: 4320 entries, 0 to 4319

dtypes: float64(2304), int64(1440), object(576)

Comment: @user2825739 I know nothing about your txt, so can't help. You can check yourself that solution works for data you provided in question, hence the code is a sample that you can elaborate for your needs. It is worthwile on SO to answer generic questions, applicable to many situations and problems, but unworthy to write and debug a code for a particular case, such an answer will be of interest for noone but questioner.

Comment: @user2825739 as for your problem with columns, you pandas can't split your lines txt, so it's issue with line delimiters